# Win 7 ESU - Feb onward updates SCCM Deployment issue

Tags: windows-7, updates, sccm

My question is regarding Win 7 ESU and updates since Feb 2020. we have installed and activated ESU MAK key on 10000+ PCs. Now for some reason Feb update*(2020-02 Security Only Quality Update for Windows 7 for x86-based Systems (KB4537813)* is showing that it is only required on 13 machines. please tell me if my understanding is wrong that this update should be required on all the machine that has ESU licence key activated?

this update >> *2020-02 Extended Security Updates (ESU) Licensing Preparation Package for Windows 7 for x86-based Systems (KB4538483)* is a prereq for ESU, but this update is required on only 228 and installed on 434. And if it is installed on 434, those 434 machines should receive Feb onward updates.....shouldn't they?

we are using Config Manager 1910.

Comment: this question belongs to serverfault.com/ not stackoverflow.com

Comment: ok thanks, i will post it there